# How do i return multiple matching columns into 1 column with VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do i return multiple matching columns into 1 column with VLOOKUP

=Arrayformula(if(len(A9:A), iferror(vlookup(B9:B, 'Concat Sheet Data'!A9:Q, {2,3}, FALSE)),))

Would like to return Column 2,3 into a single column.

Link to worksheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rMO4BU1vPJFFHPGELA_p3Z1BzJhFUt7se4v_XoozNu4/edit?usp=sharing

Is this possible?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Please share a sample sheet. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: Here you go. Thanks
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rMO4BU1vPJFFHPGELA_p3Z1BzJhFUt7se4v_XoozNu4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(LEN(A:A),VLOOKUP(A:A,{E:E,F:F&G:G},2,0),""))
```

[image]

Based on the sample sheet:

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), iferror(vlookup(B2:B, {'Concat Sheet Data'!A2:A,'Concat Sheet Data'!B2:B&'Concat Sheet Data'!C2:C}, 2, FALSE)),))
```

[image]

Comment: tried this =Arrayformula(if(len(A9:A), vlookup('Concat Sheet Data'!B9:B, {'Concat Sheet Data'!B9:B&'Concat Sheet Data'!C9:C}, 2, 0),""))

but got error VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range.

Comment: @KingMichaelKing You forgot to add the first column in which VLOOKUP looks for a value, i.e. ```vlookup('Concat Sheet Data'!B9:B, {'Concat Sheet Data'!A9:A, 'Concat Sheet Data'!B9:B&'Concat Sheet Data'!C9:C}, 2, 0)```

Comment: It is what as mentioned by @basic. It should be `=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), iferror(vlookup(B2:B, {'Concat Sheet Data'!A2:A,'Concat Sheet Data'!B2:B&'Concat Sheet Data'!C2:C}, 2, FALSE)),))`. You need to concatenate Column B and Column C and form a 2 column range for your vlookup {columnA,columnB&columnC}

Answer (score 0):

Use the fuction `=FLATTEN()` to join columns into one.

Comment: @Bronby IF, when I use flatten I can’t place the found columns (2,3) indexes into where the search key is located. It doesn’t match as should with vlookup.

Comment: But don't you want to put the result of ```2``` and ```3``` in the same column? If so, you must use ```FLATTEN``` to join the two columns rescued by ```VLOOKUP```.

It would be interesting for you to release an example spreadsheet, both with the current scenario and with the result you want to have.

For easy viewing and help.

Comment: And publish both images and the link released for editing this example sheet. That way we can access and work visually.

Comment: I have added an image to my original post. I used the {2,3} to explain how the match should look like when returned.